# Paginating custom blog script

Tags: php

I have been developing a custom blog script based in Bootstrap 4 the last few days, i am nearly done apart from the pagination on the main page, i have coded the top half with the pages (mainly getting the counts from the database) but the "Older Posts >" part is giving me issues, i have never been great with pagination.

code:

```
  <!-- Main Content -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">

        <?php 

           if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
                $page = $_GET['page'];
           } else {
                $page = 1;
           }

           $max_results = 50;
           $from = $page * $max_results - $max_results;

           $posts = DB::getInstance()->select('
                SELECT  *
                FROM    `blog_posts`
                ORDER   BY `post_date` DESC
                LIMIT   :from, :max_results',
           [
                'from' => [
                    'type' => PDO::PARAM_INT,
                    'value' => $from
                ],
                'max_results' => [
                    'type' => PDO::PARAM_INT,
                    'value' => $max_results
                ]
           ]);

           $total_results = DB::getInstance()->selectValue('SELECT count(*) FROM `blog_posts`');

           if ($total_results < 1) {
               stderr('There is <b>no</b> posts yet!');
           } else {            

        ?>

            <?php foreach($posts as $post) { ?>

            <div class="post-preview">
              <a href="post.html"><h2 class="post-title"><?= urlFriendlyUrls($post['post_title'], $post['post_id']); ?></h2></a>
              <p class="post-meta"><?= truncateArticle($post['post_body'], 250); ?></p>
              <p class="post-meta">Posted by <a href="#">Start Bootstrap</a> on <?= date("F j, Y, g:i a", strtotime($post['post_date'])); ?></p>
            </div>
            <hr>

            <?php } ?>  

        <?php } ?>  

        <!-- Pager -->
        <div class="clearfix">
          <a class="btn btn-primary float-right" href="#">Older Posts &rarr;</a>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

I don't know the best way to code in the clickable links part, any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Modify your query to limit the amount of results you get based on `$_GET['page']` using OFFSET and LIMIT or whatever PDO has.

The next step would be for your `Older Posts` button to lead to the same webpage, but with `page=$_GET['page'] - 1` in the url.

As a result, you should be going to the previous page each time you hit `Older Posts` - you might also want to limit it to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Just add following code if you want to include the page in your older posts link:

```
<a href="?page=<?php echo ($page + 1); ?>
```

I would also suggest to try to look into OOP, that would help you implement much cleaner code.

[Object  Oriented Programming in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

Comment: Thank yiou guys, i now have a route to go, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Object-Oriented Programming](https://developer.hyvor.com/tutorials/php/oop-intro) to:

- Make your code clean
- Prevent duplication
- Easily re-use it

And, also, you can use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` in MYSQL. `LIMIT 25 OFFSET 50` will select the rows 50-75.

Thanks.